Fail to change an element in an numpy.array in Python
import numpy as np
def function(1st_variable,2nd_variable):
    ratio = 1st_variable/ 2nd_variable

    y = np.power(ratio, 1.1)*0.79

    if y >= value*0.89:
        y = value*0.89

    return y

def calculate(array):
    pre_array = []
    m = len(array[:,0])
    for i in np.arange(m):
          if array[i,4] == 0:.
            array[i,2] = 0
            
          elif array[i,4] == 1:
            None

            
          elif array[i,4] == 2:
            
            live_value = array[i,5]
            new_value = function(array[i,2], live_value)

            print("New Ratio:",new_value,"\n")

            array[i,2] = new_value

            print("array:",array[i,2],"\n")

          elif array[i,4] == 3: 
            t= 5400
            array[i,2] = 0.79
            row = (array[i,0],array[i,1], array[i,2],array[i,4])
            pre_array.append(list(row))
            


array = np.array([[ 42280512, 1, 7, 0, 2, 10],
                  [ 42280233, 1, 8, 0, 2, 10],
                  [ 42280562, 1, 9, 0, 2, 10]])



What I expect:
New Ratio: 0.533623485601259
array: 0.533623485601259
New Ratio: 0.6180535097191309
array: 0.6180535097191309
New Ratio: 0.7035481925846184
array: 0.7035481925846184

This is what I get:
New Ratio: 0.533623485601259
array: 0
New Ratio: 0.6180535097191309
array: 0
New Ratio: 0.7035481925846184
array: 0
My problem is even I can print, for example; "New Ratio: 0.533623485601259" correct. I get array: 0 for each row of my array

What is value in the function def? Note 1st_variable and 2nd_variable are not valid names and will cause a syntax error.

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Looks like array dtype is int. Should be float

The solution was to change ,dtype='float' at the end of the array:
 import numpy as np
def function(st_variable,nd_variable):
    ratio_value = st_variable / nd_variable
    y = np.power(ratio_value, 1.1)*0.79

    if y >= ratio_value*0.89:
        y = ratio_value*0.89

    return y

def calculate(array):
    m = len(array[:,0])
    for i in np.arange(m):
 
          if array[i,4] == 2:
        
            new_value = function(array[i,2], 2)
            print("New Value:",new_value,"\n")

            array[i,2] = new_value
            print("array[i,2]:",array[i,2],"\n")

array = np.array([[ 42280512, 1, 7, 0, 2, 10],
                  [ 42280233, 1, 8, 0, 2, 10],
                  [ 42280562, 1, 9, 0, 2, 10]],dtype='float')

calculate(array)

It didn't show me the numbers, it wasn't equalt to zero, because it was an integer array...
The output is;
New Value: 3.115
array[i,2]: 3.115
New Value: 3.56
array[i,2]: 3.56
New Value: 4.005
array[i,2]: 4.00
